# creating a barplot with breaks and densities

Tags: r, graphics, plot, ggplot2, histogram

I am looking to create a specific kind of barplot and am not expert in ggplot2 or R graphics. The height of each bar corresponds to the density vector below.

The x-axis breaks for each bar are identified in the breaks vector. (The length of the density and the breaks vector are always identical.). The breaks are contiguous. I can guarantee that the width between breakpoints is the same for all breaks (in the example below the width is .2 for every interval).

How does one create this chart in R such that the height of the bar is the density, and the width and beginning/end of the bar is determined by the breaks vector?

```
# density for each bar
density = c(0, 2.43053372991266e-05, 0, 2.56155325481663e-05, 7.85928661230842e-05, 
6.65974683477407e-05, 0.000191167180262139, 0.000391190191728852, 
0.000773173013145194, 0.000994581155560843, 0.00186993240600829, 
0.00301523228215973, 0.0024027636820586, 0.00178958309972533, 
0.00197757576002083, 0.0037305807759235, 0.00751360121824956, 
0.0161785199339545, 0.0285084660871918, 0.0470377898959775, 0.0749650429960432, 
0.0995404136577645, 0.122970891515022, 0.137345727945268, 0.129721517357472, 
0.111609726931989, 0.0833285279873897, 0.0569221001742823, 0.034426013022441, 
0.0191745738000343, 0.00810133792335031, 0.00342022026994395, 
0.00120148435128416, 0.000598579482992183, 5.22199596137814e-05, 
5.23550471126253e-05, 0)

# breaks for barplot
breaks = c(-4.6, -4.4, -4.2, -4, -3.8, -3.6, -3.4, -3.2, -3, -2.8, -2.6, 
-2.4, -2.2, -2, -1.8, -1.6, -1.4, -1.2, -1, -0.8, -0.6, -0.399999999999999, 
-0.199999999999999, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.600000000000001, 0.800000000000001, 
1, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2, 2.2, 2.4, 2.6)
```

To illustrate, the density of the first bar is 0%. The range of the bar corresponds to -Inf to -4.6. The next bar has a height of 2.43e-05 and the x-axis has a bar that ranges from -4.6 to -4.4 on the x-axis. The second bar has height 0 and the x-axis has a bar width ranging from -4.4 to -4.2 on the x-axis, an so on. The last bar has a density of 0% and ranges from 2.6 to Infinity. (Naturally, we would set the xlim of the plot object to min and max of the breaks so that the first and last bars of 0% density are not plotted).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a ggplot2 version:

```
df <- data.frame(
  xmin = breaks,
  xmax = c(breaks[-1], Inf),
  ymin = 0,
  ymax = density)

ggplot(df, aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax)) + 
  geom_rect(colour = "grey80")
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Barplot with everything:

```
barplot(density, names.arg=breaks)
```

And this would eliminate the first and last entries:

```
barplot(density[-c(1,length(density))], names.arg=breaks[-c(1,length(density))] )
```

In order for your description to match your data you would need one more observed density than in your cutpoints vector; This will omit the two ends of the "density" and plot with what might be the right vector of character labels for intervals, but you will need to check the registration of values with labels:

```
opar <- par(mar=c(6, 4, 3, 2) + 0.1)
str.breaks <- paste(format(breaks[-length(breaks)], scientific=3),
                              "  to ", format(breaks[-1], scientific=3), sep="")
barplot(density[-c(1,length(density))], names.arg=str.breaks[-1], las=2 )
par(opar)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Dwin, after building the chart, I run the command: abline( v = 0 , col = "red" ) as a simple test. The vertical line shows up on the far left of the plot instead of on between the -.2 to 0/0 to .2 labels. Is it possible that the code above is only naming labels but not spacing the beginning and ending values of the bin according to the "breaks" vector? Thank you for your help!

Comment: It's not just possible, it's certain. The user-coordinates of the left hand side start at 1. Barplots are indexed by their order, not by the values in their labels. If you want to find the index using the numeric  'breaks' variable then use the `findInterval` function.